# Criminals and their strange slang

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> Quick, get in the boxpark! The guards are hot on our trail. The classfigure is getting intense. We need to get off this railblock as soon as possible. If they stop us and open the trunk we're brainbeat.
>
> The inside mistechnology we had allowed us to take them by surprise. Nobody was ready for the heartdog. We had copied the keytrick containing the security codes in advance, and our informant had found out the location of the hidden safe in the stonepaper.
>
> By now, everybody is probably up in forechairs. Full mobilization. No armroom until they've caught us. The acidcoat is coming down heavily. We need to cover our tracks.
>
> The streetform that we stole already has an offshore buyer lined up. No paper trail. No trail of any kind. Not a single keybook on a napkin points to us. We're like ghosts. We'll vanish into thin air if we only have enough overpiece to get to the docks before they catch us. The ship is already waiting there. Hit the gas! Go go go!

How does this exciting chase end? Looking for a one-word answer.

Comment: This was a really nice puzzle! Cute and simple, but a lot of fun to solve.

Comment: Beautiful unique concept. @Deusovi is too fast, as usual.

Comment: After looking at @Deusovi 's answer, I underestimated this puzzle! So crafty and so clever! I am personally bookmarking this! DVL12 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The trick to deciphering these slang words is that:

> each one is two words, A and B. The answer is a word that can go *after* A but *before* B in two common phrases. (For instance, "armroom" is "rest", because of the phrases "armrest" and "restroom".)

The "correct" words are:

> Quick, get in the [box]**car**[park]! The guards are hot on our trail. The [class]**action**[figure] is getting intense. We need to get off this [rail]**road**[block] as soon as possible. If they stop us and open the trunk we're [brain]**dead**[beat].
>
>  The inside [mis]**information**[technology] we had allowed us to take them by surprise. Nobody was ready for the [heart]**attack**[dog]. We had copied the [key]**card**[trick] containing the security codes in advance, and our informant had found out the location of the hidden safe in the [stone]**wall**[paper].
>
>  By now, everybody is probably up in [fore]**arms**[chairs]. Full mobilization. No [arm]**rest**[room] until they've caught us. The [acid]**rain**[coat] is coming down heavily. We need to cover our tracks.
>
>  The [street]**art**[form] that we stole already has an offshore buyer lined up. No paper trail. No trail of any kind. Not a single [key]**note**[book] on a napkin points to us. We're like ghosts. We'll vanish into thin air if we only have enough [over]**time**[piece] to get to the docks before they catch us. The ship is already waiting there. Hit the gas! Go go go!

And finally,

> reading the first letters of the real words tells us that the chase will end with CARDIAC WARRANT: decoding as one final slang word, we get **ARREST**.

Comment: Deusovi, I think you're close -- but r13(gur gjb jbeqf znqr ol gur svefg yrggre ner PNEQVNP JNEENAG, jurer vs lbh sbyybj gur fnzr gevpx lbh trg pneqvnp NEERFG jneenag -- fb gur fvatyr jbeq nafjre vf NEERFG.) Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @El-Guest Oh, *duh*! I was thinking of the first phrase in the two and apparently didn't read what I had typed! Fixing it now - thanks!